# Can a git alias be expanded like a bash alias?

Tags: bash, git, alias

If I set the alias `alias gf='git fetch --prune'`

I can enter it into my command line `$ gf` and by typing `<ESC> <C-e>` it will expand into `$ git fetch --prune`

If I set the git alias `git config --global alias.f fetch --prune` and type `$ git f` does git offer a way of expanding this alias?

From what I can tell the only way to know what `$ git f` will do when executed is by inspecting git's config beforehand.

Comment: Taking your question literally: *does git offer a way of expanding this alias?* the answer is yes: `git config alias.f` shows the content of the alias. The problem with the literal answer is that you probably want *shell expansion*, not git. Then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, considering git aliases can also include [shell expansion definition](https://blog.theodo.fr/2017/06/git-game-advanced-git-aliases/#whatisthebangfor) aliases with positional parameters like `"!f() { echo \"$1\" >> .gitignore; }; f".`.

And that would be tricky to expand on the shell level.